# How to convert a class to dynamic parent interface?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a generic interface and some corresponding code(All the codes below are in the `ClassLibrary1` namespace):

```
interface IProcessor<T>
{
    void process(T message);
}

public class Second{/*Store some message*/}
public class First{/*Store some message*/}

public enum MessageType
{
    First,
    Second
}
```

and a `Processor` class

```
public class Processor : IProcessor<First>,IProcessor<Second>
{
    public void process(First message){/*process the "First" type message*/}
    public void process(Second message){/*process the "Second" type message*/}
}
```

So I had several overload version of `process` method.

I write a `dispatcher` class:

```
public partial class Dispatcher
{
    private const string NS_BASE = "ClassLibrary1";
    private static Processor processor = new Processor();
    static partial void Dispatch(MessageType msgType, Object message);
    static partial void Dispatch_cached(MessageType msgType, Object message);
    // basic declaration above, implemntation follows
    // message parameter corresponds with msgType.The method signature is compulsory and can't be modified()
}
```

I first used direct reflection:

```
public partial class Dispatcher
{    
    static partial void Dispatch(MessageType msgType,Object message)
    {
        Type messageType = Type.GetType(NS_BASE + "." + msgType.ToString());
        Type processorType = typeof(Processor);
        Type[] typeArr = new Type[] { messageType };
        Object[] msgArr = new Object[] { message };
        MethodInfo processMethod = processorType.GetMethod("process", typeArr);
        processMethod.Invoke(processor, msgArr);
    }
}
```

And improve the performance using cache:

```
public partial class Dispatcher
{    
    private static Dictionary<String, MethodInfo> typeDictionary = initDict();

    private static Dictionary<String, MethodInfo> initDict()
    {
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MessageType));
        return names.ToDictionary(msgTypeStr => msgTypeStr, msgTypeStr =>
        {
            Type messageType = Type.GetType(NS_BASE + "." + msgTypeStr.ToString());
            Type processorType = typeof(Processor);
            Type[] typeArr = new Type[] { messageType };
            return processorType.GetMethod("process", typeArr);
        });
    }

    static partial void Dispatch_cached(MessageType msgType, Object message)
    {
        if (typeDictionary.TryGetValue(msgType.ToString(), out MethodInfo processorMethod))
        {
            Object[] msgArr = new Object[] { message };
            processorMethod.Invoke(processor, msgArr);
        }
    }
}
```

The performance actually improved 5~6 times according to my test, but i also see possible reflection alternatives such as expression,emit or DLR. **So do these alternative solutions fit in the scene and will they improve performance?**

These are problems that I actually face.'How to convert a class to dynamic parent interface?' is just a qustion I come up with when trying to solve it using DLR.

```
static void Dispatch_dynamic(MessageType msgType, dynamic message)
{
    processor.process(message);// I think this line will raise a runtime error
    //can I convert processor to IFoo<First/Second> type and call the processor_converted.process(message)?
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve. You won't change the type of the object itself - normally you cast to use a specific set of members of a type that you know about at compile-time. If you can give more information about what you're trying to do - ideally as a [mcve] - we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: question updated

Comment: @JonSkeet question updated

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways this could be done - but I don't want to work up the [mcve] to test them myself, when that feels like it's more appropriate for you to do. Not pseudo-code like is currently in the question (`do` is a keyword, and would be a non-idiomatic method name anyway) but a full example.

Comment: @JonSkeet question updated.Previously I was typing on the smartphone...Sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: From my experience, in order to call a dynamic method fast, you have to know the signature. One of the absolute slowest ways to do it is `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` and that is because the signature is not known. One of the fastest is to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to get back a strongly typed delegate. Those are very very fast. But still, it may not matter if this is not performance critical code. `MethodInfo.Invoke`, which is what you're using, is probably fast enough.

Comment: "I think this line will raise a runtime error" - I think that it won't raise a runtime error. Did you try it?

Comment: @TannerSwett then how do the runtime determine which overload method to invoke?

Comment: By looking at whether `message` has runtime type `First` or `Second`.